# When should a personal blog's tutorial not be included in a community wiki answer?

Tags: discussion

I had been working on a [JMeter tutorial on my blog](http://dudewheysmehblog.blogspot.com/p/compilations.html) and saw [this question asking for JMeter tutorials](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/where-can-i-find-good-jmeter-tutorials).  I thought it was a good fit for the question, seeing as how other blogs were on the list, yet my addition was deleted.  Why?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a site to link to blogs. This is a site to give answers. That question has an accepted answer that links to a LOT of different sources. Just Linking to a blog is NOT an answer which is why your post was deleted.

Comment: Understood, but I had added it to the existing answer.  If you look at the existing answer, the actual link is still there (#12), just the reference has been deleted.